# JDBC -- not enough values

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a MySQL table, `EMPLOYEES`, which has the following form:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES
(
        FNAME           VARCHAR(15)             NOT NULL,
        LNAME           VARCHAR(15)             NOT NULL,
        PHONE           CHAR(10),
        HOURS           INT                     NOT NULL,
        EMPLOYEE_NUM    CHAR(5)                 NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_NUM)
);
```

I'm attempting to write a program which allows me to manipulate the table. I have the following method to attempt to do this.

```
void addEmployee(Connection conn) throws SQLException, IOException {

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 

    String fName = readEntry("First name: ");
    String lName = readEntry("Last name: ");
    String phoneNumber = readEntry("Phone number: ");
    String hours = readEntry("Number of hours worked: ");
    String employeeNum = readEntry("Employee Number: ");
    String query = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES ('" +
            fName + "','" + lName + "','" + phoneNumber + "'," + hours + ",'" + employeeNum + "')";
    try {
      int nrows = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Adding Catalog Entry");
        while (e != null) {
          System.out.println("Message     : " + e.getMessage());
          e = e.getNextException();
        }
        return;
      }
    stmt.close();
    System.out.println("Added Catalog Entry");
}
```

When I try to execute this call:

```
First name: fname
Last name: lname
Phone number: 
Number of hours worked: 34
Employee Number: 01923
Error Adding Catalog Entry
Message     : ORA-00947: not enough values
```

In this attempt, I left "phoneNumber" blank for NULL. In an earlier attempt I gave it a phone number and got the same message.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

If any crucial information is missing, let me know and I can add it.

Thanks,
erip

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement`, you might also consider providing the order of the columns `insert into EMPLOYEES  (FNAME, LNAME, PHONE, HOURS, EMPLOYEE_NUM) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`.  See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

When you do an `insert`, you should *always* list the columns.

Does this work?

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(fname, lname, phoneNumber, hours, employee_Num)
      VALUES ('" +fName + "','" + lName + "','" + phoneNumber + "'," + hours + ",'" + employeeNum + "')
```

Comment: *"Does this work?"* Seems to make it a comment ;) - Also, one should always use `PreparedStatement`s